# Angular 9 Reactive Form - Removing the last control and get Valid on Form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

Im looking to resolve this issue but i didn't find a solution, i was looking in lot of topics but nothing works.

**-Im removing a form control but when i removed the last form control, the form still with Status="valid"**

Tried with .clearValidators(); .updateValueAndValidity(); and not works

Thank you so much for the help.
Regards

Function to init the Empty form

```
initForm() {
    this.formTurbine =  this.formBuilder.group({});
  }
```

Function to add controls dynamically

```
randomFunction() {
 for (...) {
  if (condition to add control) {
  this.form.addControl(this.oneArray[i].name, this.formBuilder.control('', [Validators.required]));
   }
  }
}
```

Function to remove control dynamically

```
randomFunction(controlToRemove) {
 for (...) {
  if (condition to remove control) {
  this.form.removeControl(controlToRemove);
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: So to be clear, your form has no more controls but you are saying the status on the form is valid? Why would you expect it to be invalid when there are no more controls available which need to have required attributes in order to invalidate the form?

Comment: yes, make sense. So i will need to make it invalid by other way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

add: this.form = ...this.form
sometimes it helps angular re analize some stuff. forgot the science behind it.